# regex to get a substring where the main string's ending is also the substring's enging

Tags: python, regex

```
title= re.findall(r"[#]([^\s#@$\\|]*)(?=[\s#@$\\|])", content)
```

I have this regex function with which I want to get all the values in a string if they start with a hash sign. But I couldn't get it to work if a substring is at the end of the string and nothing fallows it. I've tried to remove the first "$" but it didn't work. It works when I append one space to the string but as I'm going to modify the function to ignore spaces I don't want to do it anymore.

For example if the string is:

```
a="#title1 #title2 #title3"
```

The result is:

```
{"title1","title2"}
```

But I want it to be:

```
{"title1","title2","title3"}
```

Comment: `(?=[\s#@$\\|])` => `(?=[\s#@$\\|]|$)`

Comment: dziekuje Wiktor!